# Tutorials on object-oriented programming in R

Tags: r

Are there good tutorials on object-oriented programming in R?

It would be great if it included the following:

- how to define a class;
- differences between S3 and S4 classes;
- operator overloading (I'd like to be able to write `a+b` where `a` and `b` are instances of the class I have in mind).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hadley Wickham's wiki on [devtools](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/) is a great resource for the necessary information in a concise form. However, if you want an exhaustive resource, the R language manual's [OOP](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Object_002doriented-programming) section may be helpful. I am sure more experienced members will have better suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to [@suncoolsu](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4575/tutorials-on-object-oriented-programming-in-r/4576#4576) excellent response, there is [A (Not So) Short Introduction to S4](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Genolini-S4tutorialV0-5en.pdf), by Christophe Genolini. It is available on CRAN website.

Answer (score 4):

Hadley Wickham's "[Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html#oo)" has some very good intro and references.
I am replicating this section for better indexing.

> Picking a system
>
> Three OO systems is a lot for one language, but for
> most R programming, S3 suffices. In R you usually create fairly simple
> objects and methods for pre-existing generic functions like print(),
> summary(), and plot(). S3 is well suited to this task, and the
> majority of OO code that I have written in R is S3. S3 is a little
> quirky, but it gets the job done with a minimum of code.
>
> If you are creating more complicated systems of interrelated objects,
> S4 may be more appropriate. A good example is the Matrix package by
> Douglas Bates and Martin Maechler. It is designed to efficiently store
> and compute with many different types of sparse matrices. As of
> version 1.1.3, it defines 102 classes and 20 generic functions. The
> package is well written and well commented, and the accompanying
> vignette (vignette("Intro2Matrix", package = "Matrix")) gives a good
> overview of the structure of the package. S4 is also used extensively
> by Bioconductor packages, which need to model complicated
> interrelationships between biological objects. Bioconductor provides
> many good resources for learning S4. If you’ve mastered S3, S4 is
> relatively easy to pick up; the ideas are all the same, it is just
> more formal, more strict, and more verbose.
>
> If you’ve programmed in a mainstream OO language, RC will seem very
> natural. But because they can introduce side effects through mutable
> state, they are harder to understand. For example, when you usually
> call f(a, b) in R you can assume that a and b will not be modified.
> But if a and b are RC objects, they might be modified in the place.
> Generally, when using RC objects you want to minimise side effects as
> much as possible, and use them only where mutable states are
> absolutely required. The majority of functions should still be
> “functional”, and free of side effects. This makes code easier to
> reason about and easier for other R programmers to understand.

He references "[A practical tutorial on S4 programming](https://bioconductor.org/help/course-materials/2013/CSAMA2013/friday/afternoon/S4-tutorial.pdf)".

There are a number of other interesting resources if you follow his pointers.

John M. Chambers says in ["Object-Oriented Programming, Functional Programming and R"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.3531v1.pdf):

> R has also been strongly influenced by the ideas of functional
> programming and, in particular, by the desire to combine functional
> with object oriented programming

Would add something not directly related to the question but along the same idea: ["DataFrames in Spark for Large Scale Data Science"](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/02/17/introducing-dataframes-in-spark-for-large-scale-data-science.html). Since this brings closer Scala and R, there might a great OO/functional synergy coming out of this.